# wlan0 to eth0 bridge maintaining raspberry pi access to eth0

Tags: pi-3, networking, bridge

I have had success following this tutorial and have an access point bridged to ethernet.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

My question is once you bridge wlan0 with eth0, can the Raspberry Pi still access the eth0 and connect to devices on the other end? I would like to still be able to use the Pi with eth0 as well as bridge to it from wlan0.

Comment: To further clarify, I have a digital mixer connected via ethernet to my Pi. I was able to control it perfectly through the software provided by the manufacturer. In an attempt to allow wireless devices to connect to the mixer as well using the minimal amount of hardware possible I set the Raspberry Pi up as an AP and added br0 to bridge eth0 and wlan0. I can now connect to the Raspberry Pi AP and control the mixer from other wireless device but can no longer "see" the mixer from the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

A bridge does not work with ip addresses. It only uses mac addresses. That is the reason why you do not see an ip address on member interfaces of a bridge like **wlan0** and **eth0** if you show it with `ip addr`. It doesn`t help if you give these interfaces ip addresses. They will loose them as soon as you add them to the bridge. So you cannot use **eth0** for connections anymore.

But this does not mean that you cannot connect to devices on the other end. The interface **br0** replaces **eth0**. So just give **br0** an ip address and use it as you have used **eth0** before.